# android - mime type - use of asterisk

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I tried the following test :

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.android.intenttest-2.activity2_action"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="*/jpeg" />

 </intent-filter>

 Intent i = new Intent();
 i.setAction("com.android.intenttest-2.activity2_action");
 i.setType("image/jpeg");
 startActivity(i);
```

Should this intent match the intent filter ? (I'm getting a failed match in `Android 4.4`).

Comment: how are you setting the data for this intent? i.setData() ? Quoted from android documentation : "If you want to set both the URI and MIME type, do not call setData() and setType() because they each nullify the value of the other. Always use setDataAndType() to set both URI and MIME type."

Comment: I am not using URI. I am just using mime type. So I used setType in the intent. Is that okay ?

Comment: Is it legal to use `*` as the type with an explicit sub-type? As far as I know the `jpeg` sub-type is only relevant to the `image` type so specifying `*/jpeg` doesn't really make sense. I may be wrong though.

Comment: Seems like it isn't legal or supported on Android. It works if you change the intent filter to "image/jpeg" or "`*/`*". Eclipse tells me that the action name shouldn't have a hyphen in it.